# using one AsyncTask instead of two AsyncTasks in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have the following scenario: in my application I am using AsyncTask A to connect to the database and check the login. This AsyncTask's doInBackground method returns a boolean value.
For some user interaction I am using AsyncTask B to connect to the same database and get back a ResultSet. 
Everything is working fine, but I want to use only one AsyncTask. How can I do this?

AsyncTask A code

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    String username = arg0[0];
    String password = arg0[1];

    Boolean v = false;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = null;


    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, user, passwd);

        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            try {
                rs = stmt
                        .executeQuery("execute"
                                + username + "'");

                if (rs.next()) {
                    String p=rs.getString("pass_word");
                    if (p==null){
                        if(password.equals(""))
                            v = true;}
                    else
                        if(p.equals(password))
                            v=true;
                }

            } finally {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (Throwable ignore) {
                }
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Throwable ignore) {
            }
        }

    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.lang.ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return v;

}
```

AsyncTask B code

```
@Override
protected ResultSet doInBackground(String... params) {

    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        if (conn == null) {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, user, passwd);
        }

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(params[0]);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs;
}
```

Comment: Can you include some code?

Comment: and if login exist, what kind of action do you perfom?

Comment: @Cornholio added some code

Comment: @Sajmon I am just starting a new Activity

Comment: create a class extends ASYNCTASK..and override its all methods..pre,do and post.

Comment: Consider if it's really worth making the task more complex. Better have two simple tasks that are easy to maintain and modify than one complex. KISS - Keep it simple, seriously!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a mock implementation that should work:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Params, Void, Integer> {
    private ResultSet result;
    private int option;

    public MyTask(int option) {
        this.option = option;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Params... params) {
        switch (option) {
            case checkLogin: {
                // Do checks from first Asynctask here and return an int like normal
            } case getResults: {
                // Get your resultSet here and store:
                this.result = results;
            }
        }
    }

    public ResultSet getResults() {
        if (this.result != null) { 
            return this.result;
        } else {
            // Throw error or log message here
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to extend `AsyncTask<Params, Void, Object>` and then you can pass whatever you want, instead of using another method to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Append the code that was performed in task B in task A's `doInBackground` method. Use the `onPostExecute` method to perform any post processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an  onPreExecute() checks the login.
then doInBackground(Params...) to get back a ResultSet

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html describes better

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you could do (supposing there will be further cases of database access in your app) would be to use your AsyncTask B (which is already pretty generic anyway) as a **base class** for all your other tasks and extend tasks for special cases like the login from it and just override the `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods as needed.

So, you could rewrite your AsyncTask A by extending AsyncTask B and move the checking of the result set to onPostExecute. Or, if this is too time consuming, you could extend the generic AsyncTask B by a `handleResultSetInBackground` method which you'd call within `doInBackground` after you've got the ResultSet and which you could override in your derived classes.